# How do I present the UIPickerview to a user in my app?

Tags: ios, css, xcode, uipickerview

I have a universal app that requires two text inputs to display a list of options to choose from. I believe the UIPickerView is the best thing for this. However when I display it on the app it does not look good. Is there a standard practice on how this element should be presented ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved by dynamically creating the picker and assigning the picker to a text element.